# Limited size of MySQL INSERT

Tags: server, php, sql

I am inserting data from `.csv` to MySQL database using PHP but I can't INSERT more than 922 lines.
Every time the number of the lines is different, usually it is 841 or 837 but after restart my mysql-server PC it has the maximum number – 922 rows.
I am runing Ubuntu Server 16.04.

`vi /var/log/mysql/error.log` is:

```
0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 223238094ms. 
The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: Could that be related with the php memory limits? (max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit). Consider checking the values and play with bigger ons if they have a similar size then your import-file.

Answer (score 1):

It is was a time limit of the page (30 sec)
Just add the line 
set_time_limit(0); 
It will  remove time limit at all . And now all work fine.

Comment: where can I set the set_time_limit variable?